# .NET API for Connecting to Bugzilla

Tags: c#, .net, api, bugzilla

I am looking for a library to connect to Bugzilla which works with C#.  I did find the [Bugzilla C# Proxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bugzproxy/), but it's not quite what I'm looking for.  I haven't been able to find anything else through Google searches.  Does anybody have any other suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know of anything else, but perhaps some more specifics on what you are looking for and why the project you link to does not meet your requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using the [Bugzilla C# Proxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bugzproxy/) for some operations and wrote a little class that fetched the bug  XML when I needed more in depth information about the bug. Note I had to modify the Bugzilla C# Proxy to expose the CookieContainer so I could use it for authentication for my XML requests.

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(string.Format(_url, buggid));
        request.CookieContainer = _cookies;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ProhibitDtd = false;
        settings.XmlResolver = null;
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.None;

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(responseFromServer);
        XmlReader xreader = XmlReader.Create(sr, settings);

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(xreader);
```

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem also several month ago. And we did not find anything. To communicate with bugzilla we wrote cgi script, which uses internal Bugzilla api. And just call our cgi script methods by http requests from C# code.